# How can I play games that need Quicktime?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, windows-10, backwards-compatibility, gundam0079-the-war-for-earth

I am trying to play *Gundam 0079: The War for Earth* for PC on Windows 10, but every time I boot it up it does not work. It says "Quicktime was not installed right", or something like that. But even if I reinstall it, it still gives that error and also this game is not on steam or gog so yeah.